# Dynamic sql is truncated with exec attempted

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, truncation

Here is my SP:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[_spwf_Deps](@process_name varchar(64), @deps varchar(250))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @loop varchar(max);

SET @deps = REPLACE(@deps, ',', '= 1 AND ');
SET @loop = '''WHILE (select count(*) from dbo.tblDeps where Process_name = 
''''@process_name'''' and @deps = 1) = 0 BEGIN WAITFOR DELAY ''''00:00:02'''' break; END;''';

SET @loop = REPLACE(REPLACE(@loop, '@process_name', @process_name), '@deps', @deps);

print @loop;

exec (@loop);

END;
```

The PRINT statement prints things out just fine and I can exec that string.

But the `exec` command fails with this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'WHILE (select count(*) from dbo.tblDeps where Process_name = 'proc' and dep_one= 1 AND dep_two = 1) = 0 BEGIN WAITF'.

As you can see, the string is truncated and hence the error.

`@loop` is `varchar(MAX)` so everything should fit.

Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you want the entire string in quotes? Changing the beginning to `'WHILE ...` and the end to `... END;'` ought to help. The truncation you see is likely just a side effect of formatting the error message.

Comment: You are playing with fire, handling parameters in dynamic SQL like that. Research [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) and how parameters are passed to a dynamic SQL string. Also, supply a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) to your procedure for multiple values, don't juggle with comma-separated strings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to closely recreate the error. Remove the extra quotes from @loop and you should be good.

```
SET @loop = 'WHILE (select count(*) from dbo.tblDeps where Process_name = 
''@process_name'' and @deps = 1) = 0 BEGIN WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:02'' break; END;';
```